# iText - add Table at the end of last page IF Space available

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am using iText 2.1.7
I write a pdf document for which the page size and contant can differ each time. What i want to achieve is a table at the very last page and at the bottom of that page. I am aware of the method 'writeSelectedRows', but with this it could happen that i overwrite text on the page, because i dont know if there is space for my table.

So in conclusion:
If i have reached the last page i want to add my table at the bottom of the page. But if the table does not fit, i want a new page and on this page i want to add the table at the bottom.
I could not find a solution so far.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the code examples in the answers below are for iText 5. You are using iText 2.1.7, which is unsupported and past end-of-life. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/itext/3557/getting-started-with-itext#t=201703151411361159498&a=versions. The answers may or may not work for you. I recommend that you upgrade to a more recent version. Current version is 5.5.10; 5.5.11 will be released today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this http://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/1910 to calculate the height of a table and then check the available space on a page with PdfWriter.GetVerticalPostition(). You might want to consider your Document.BottomMargin or some other offset in your space calculation. (v4.1.6)

Answer (score -1):

Check out this link:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/general-questions-about-itext/itext7-how-find-out-current-cursor-position-page

I suppose that once you know the current cursor position on this page, you can write a simple if-statement to add a new page, or not.

Kind regards,
Joris